# how to calculate percentage variation between two values?

Tags: python

I have this dataframe with the total population number by year.

```
import pandas as pd
cases_df = pd.DataFrame(data=cases_list, columns=['Year', 'Population', 'Nation'])
cases_df.head(7)



 Year       Population       Nation
0   2019    328239523   United States
1   2018    327167439   United States
2   2017    325719178   United States
3   2016    323127515   United States
4   2015    321418821   United States
5   2014    318857056   United States
6   2013    316128839   United States
```

I want to calculate how much the population has increased from the year 2013 to 2019 by calculating the percentage change between two values (2013 and 2019):

```
{[(328239523 - 316128839)/ 316128839] x 100 }
```

How can I do this? Thank you very much!!

ps. some advice to remove index? `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`

i tried to to that

```
df1 = df.groupby(level='Population').pct_change() 
print(df1)
```

but i get error because "Population" says that is not the name of Index

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":[2015,2014,2013],"population":[321418821,318857056,316128839],"nation":["United States","United States","United States"]})
df = df.set_index("year")
df["percentage"] = df["population"] * 100 / df["population"][2013]
print(df)
```

output

```
      population         nation  percentage
year
2015   321418821  United States  101.673363
2014   318857056  United States  100.863008
2013   316128839  United States  100.000000
```

Note I used subset of data for brevity sake. Using year as index allow easy access to population value in 2013, percentage is computed as (population) * 100 / (population for 2013).

Comment: The right operation is (pop 2019 - pop 2013)/ pop 2013 x 100. How can i write that good on the code basing on your code?

Answer (score 0):

How to remove the mentioned index :

```
df.set_index('Year',inplace=True)
```

Now Year will replace your numbered index.

Now

Use `cases_df.describe()`
or `cases_df.attribute_name.describe()`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a math question rather than a programming question.

Let's call this a percentage **difference** between two values since population can vary both ways (increase or decrease over time).

Now, lets say that in 2013 we had `316128839` people and in 2019 we had `328239523` people:

```
a = 316128839
b = 328239523
```

Before we go about calculating the percentage, we need to find the difference between the `b` and `a`:

```
diff = b - a
```

Now that we have that, we need to see what is the percentage of `diff` of `a`:

```
perc = (diff / a) * 100
```

And there is your percentage variation between `a` and `b`